# is there a way to use completion of an activity to trigger a contact's status change

Tags: civimember

Contacts who apply to become volunteers can select 'Befriending Volunteer' (a subset of volunteers) as a preference.

Once they pass all checks to become volunteers, their Volunteer status changes to 'approved' and the volunteer coordinator marks their Befriender status as 'pending'

The befriending team then adds a Befriender Training activity to their record; if they attend/pass, their Befriender status is updated to 'approved'.

I am wondering if there would be a (simple) way to make the status update automatic, so that once I mark the attendees as 'complete', their contact's status is automatically updated to 'approved'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with CiviRules using the "Compare Old Activity Status to New Activity Status" trigger and then setting the status of the custom field as the linked action.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer; that might be beyond my capabilities, but I'll read about it and hopefully will work it out.